# Sorting list of lists with a third list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `a` containing rows (also lists) with three elements each. I want to sort those according to the values in a list `b` in ascending order. I tried the following:

```py
a = [[1,2,3],['hi','foo','fi'],[7,8,9]]
print(a)
b = [0.3,3,0.6]

keydict = dict(zip(a,b))
a.sort(key=keydict.get)
```

However im getting the error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

in the line with `keydict = dict(zip(a,b))`.

I expect to get this:

```py
a = [[1,2,3],[7,8,9],['hi','foo','fi']]
```

What could i do to make it right?

Comment: Of course sorry

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: x[0], sorted(zip(a, b), key=lambda x: x[1])))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comprehension with `sorted` and a custom key is the solution:

```
>>> [x for _, x in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: b[x[0]])]
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], ['hi', 'foo', 'fi']]
```

Or using `zip`:

```
>>> [x for _, x in sorted(zip(b, a))]
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], ['hi', 'foo', 'fi']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `sorted` with a `key` to get the indices that would sort `b` and use it to sort `a` using a list comprehension:

```
[a[i] for i in sorted(range(len(b)), key=b.__getitem__)]
# [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], ['hi', 'foo', 'fi']]
```